# Java beginner manually enter values and print details of object void main

Tags: java, oop, methods

I am new to Java and was wondering how to display details through

```
public static void main(String [] args){
```

For example I have a classes, and I need make a separate class called ClassSeperate which sole purpose is to create an object with valid values from the NewCar class and print them using

```
 public static void main(String [] args){
```

Say i make this class and have the right constructors accessors and such etc etc

```
Public class NewCar,

private String carMake;
private String carColor
private int carYear
private int kmsDriven;
```

I want to implement my own values and set the number of kmsDriven to 50.

So I go to the SeperateClass and type in

```
public static void main(String [] args){`

NewCar car = new NewCar("FERRARI","YELLOW",2020,50)
System.out.println(?)
```

I am not quite sure how to print those details i just put into the object in void main. `I tried System.out.println(car.toString());` but when i click on the void main nothing pops up? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Look up encapsulation and accessor methods.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I print my Java object without getting "SomeType@2f92e0f4"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4)

Comment: `System.out.println(car.toString());` is what you want, assuming your `NewCar` overrides `toString`.

Comment: You will either need to override the toString() method, or use getters (methods such as getMake(), getColor(), getYear(), and getDriven().

Comment: Wouldpublic static void main ever output a System.out.println?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a little example

```
public class foo {
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;

  public String getFirstname () {
    return firstName;
  }

  public String getLastname () {
    return lastName;
  }

  public String toString () {
    return firstName + " " + lastName;
  }
}
```

Now you can print both names via

```
foo f = ...;
System.out.println(f.getFirstName() + " " + f.getLastName());
```

or

```
for f = ...;
System.out.println(f.toString());
```

--

FYI- In Eclipse and many IDEs, if you declare your member variable (firstName,lastName) the IDE can generate getters and setters for you

Answer (score 1):

Put the following function in `NewCar` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "NewCar [carMake=" + carMake + ", carColor=" + carColor + ", carYear=" + carYear + ", kmsDriven=" + kmsDriven
            + "]";
}
```

Now, when you print the `car` by using the statement, `System.out.println(car);`, you will get the following output:

```
NewCar [carMake=FERRARI, carColor=YELLOW, carYear=2020, kmsDriven=50]
```

Note that I haven't written the `toString` method myself. My IDE generated it for me e.g. I am using Eclipse IDE where I right-click > **Source** > **Generate toString** to get it auto-generated.

If you do not override `toString` function in `NewCar` class and try to print `car` by using `System.out.println(car);`, you will get the output as mentioned  [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

I hope, it helps. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: thank you!  I am using a basic compiler blueJ, 
Would  public static void main ever output a System.out.println?

Comment: You are most welcome. For compilation and result perspective, it doesn't matter whether you are using Eclipse or BlueJ.  If you put the `toString` method mentioned in my answer, you will get the same result irrespective of the IDE you use. IDEs are different in terms of utility features they provide e.g. BlueJ may auto-generate the `toString` method in a different way or even it may not have the feature to auto-generate the `toString` method at all.